# page injected via jsquery/ajax does not show properly in any Chromium browser

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, chromium

as obviously the css related to the page being injected is not loaded by Chromium. However, it is working well in IE8/O 10.x/FF3.6x.

Hence begs the question - my stupidity in html coding, Chromium bug or jquery bug? that is what I could think of.

this is the page in question, eliminated all non-essential js http://logistik-experte.gmxhome.de/test.html, navigate to resume and see the difference. It is basically driving me nuts as missing the point somewhere and hence any sound advice/help would be highly appreciated.

cheers

Comment: I must be missing something, because it looks fine in my copy of Chrome (version 5.0.375.127).  Have you cleared your cache and possibly restarted your browser? http://imgur.com/24yMK.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Buggabill: works for me in Chrome 5. (At least on the server; there may be issues with loading files from a local filesystem.)

However there are problems with your approach. By having page content loaded by script only, you have made your page inaccessible to non-JavaScript users, which includes all search engines. Also you can't use the back button and the pages are unbookmarkable, un-open-in-new-tab-able, and so on.

Basically you've reinvented all the problems of `<frameset>`, the reasons why no-one uses frames any more. You shouldn't really deploy this kind of solution until you are familiar with the ways accessibility and usability can be served. At the very least, you need to point the navigation links to the real pages containing their content. Then consider allowing hash-based navigation, so the dynamically-loaded pages have a unique URL which can be navigated between, and which will re-load the selected page at load time when the URL is first entered.

Also if you are loading content into the page you should take care to load only the content you want, for example using `load('portfolio.html #somewrapperdiv')`. Otherwise you are inserting the complete HTML, including `<!DOCTYPE>` and `<head>` and all that, which clearly makes no sense.

To be honest, as it currently is, I don't see the point of the dynamic loading. You have spent a bunch of time implementing an unusual navigation scheme with many disadvantages over simple separate navigable pages, but no obvious advantage.

Comment: thanks for checking in. it is working in chromium but it does not load the page related css and there is a difference in layout between chromium based browser and IE/FF/O on the other hand. IE/FF/O do load the respective css. it might be more clear not using the test page but the root http://logistik-experte.gmxhome.de

as for the structure, I prefer not reload the header and the slideshow, which is saving bandwith/speed.

I am aware that js disabled browsers will not display the site, but thanks for pointing there.

question remains though - chromium bug as the other browsers play nicely?

Comment: http://imgur.com/hSIDU.png, that is how it looks when the css is properly applied

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, yeah, that's what I said about loading the whole document into `#about_us`. The target document contains `<style>` elements which it is invalid to insert into the document body. Maybe some browsers will still let you, but it's not something you should be relying on. Keep the styles in a global stylesheet and load only a fragment of target page, containing only elements it's actually valid to put in the place in the document you're putting them.

Comment: heads up for the feedback, got if finally settled. took out all the overhead from the sub-pages and left text. now chromium is loading also the related style sheet and shows the resume pages as supposed to... big thanks!